# Alert not showing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, alert, calculator

This was solved in the comments, so there is nothing I can mark as correct.

I'm pretty sure that it used to work, but opening it again after about a year, now it doesn't. Does anyone know why the last alert doesn't show? It's supposed to calculate my allowance from my grades, the final alrt is supposed to give all of the individual grades plus my total allowance.

```
<head>
<script>
    //alert('loaded');
function Runme() {
    //alert("running");
    //grades.gradess.submit();
    var Mathematics = Number(grades.Mathematics.value);
    var OMathematics = Number(grades.OMathematics.value);
    var Sci = Number(grades.Sci.value);
    var OSci = Number(grades.OSci.value);
    var ELA = Number(grades.ELA.value);
    var OELA = Number(grades.OELA.value);
    var SS = Number(grades.SS.value);
    var OSS = Number(grades.OSS.value);
    var Elec1 = Number(grades.Elec1.value);
    var OElec1 = Number(grades.OElec1.value);
    var Elec2 = Number(grades.Elec2.value);
    var OElec2 = Number(grades.OElec2.value);
    var Elec3 = Number(grades.Elec3.value);
    var OElec3 = Number(grades.OElec3.value);
    var Owed = 0.0;
    var outString = "";
    function Calc(n, o, name) {
    var add = 0.0;
    //alert (n + "and" + o)
        if (n >= 80) {
            add = add + 0.5;
            //alert(add + "x>80")
        }
        if (n >= 90) {
                add = add + 1.5;
            //alert(add + "x>90")
        }
        if (n >= 95) {
            add = add + 1;
            //alert(add + "x>95")
        }   
        if (n > o) {
            add = add + 0.5*(n-o);
            //alert(add + "Raised grade")
        }
        if (n < o) {
            if (o > 95) { 
                add = add - 0.25*(95-n);
                //alert(add + "lowered grade")
            }
            else if (o < 95) {
                add = add - 0.25*(o-n);
                //alert(add + "lowered grade")
            }
        }
        alert("You get $" + add + " in " + name);
        outString = " " + outString + "You get $" + add + " in " + name;
        Owed = Owed + add
    };
    Calc(Mathematics, OMathematics, "Math");
    Calc(Sci, OSci, "Science");
    Calc(ELA, OELA, "Literature");
    Calc(SS, OSS, "Social Studies/History");
    Calc(Elec1, OElec1, "Elective 1");
    Calc(Elec2, OElec2, "Elective 2");
    Calc(Elec3, OElec3, "Elective 3");
    alert("hi");
    alert(outstring + " You get $" + Owed + "!");
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
<form name="grades" action="" method="get">
<br><br>Math &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Old Math<br><input type=number size=20 name=Mathematics> <input type=number size=20 name=OMathematics>
<br><br>Science &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Old Science<br><input type=number size=20 name=Sci><input type=number size=20 name=OSci>
<br><br>English &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Old English<br><input type=number size=20 name=ELA><input type=number size=20 name=OELA>
<br><br>Social Studies &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Old Social Studies<br><input type=number size=20 name=SS>
<input type=number size=20 name=OSS>
<br><br>Elective One &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Old Elective One<br><input type=number size=20 name=Elec1><input type=number size=20 name=OElec1>
<br><br>Elective Two &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Old Elective Two<br><input type=number size=20 name=Elec2><input type=number size=20 name=OElec2>
<br><br>Elective Three &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Old Elective Three<br><input type=number size=20 name=Elec3><input type=number size=20 name=OElec3>
</form>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit and Calculate" onclick="Runme()"/>
</center>

</body>
```

Comment: Check if there is an error in the console and post it.
It think JS fails because you want to alert `outstring` but you only used `outString` before.

Comment: Because of `Uncaught ReferenceError: outstring is not defined `. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScipt](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is a typo in a variable name.

Comment: This is _JavaScript_ being case-sensitive.

Comment: Yup, it's been too long since I did Javascript. Why didn't I check the errors? :P

Comment: The entities in the html portion of the code you've posted are misspelled - the terminating `;` is consistently missing.

Comment: @collapsar YOu don't terminate with ; in html, you close with </tagname>

Comment: @AidanEdwards: i'm talking about html _entities_ (eg. `&nbsp;`), not _tags_.

Comment: @collapsar either way, it still works.

Comment: @AidanEdwards: It works because you have a tolerant application. Expect your markup to break any processor which is standard-conformant. of course, if you only generate code for user agents, it's   but a bad habit, ymmv ...